# Apply Singular Value Decomposition on input image

Tags: image-processing, svd

I want to apply SVD to an input image and do a feature extraction. This is my code snippet:

```
[row, col] = size (A);
for i = 1 : row
    for j = 1 : col
        [U,S,V] = svd(A(i,j));
    end
end
```

Here `A` is the input image whose row = `347275` and col = `64`. After executing the code I get `U = 1`, `V = 1` and `S = 1.4981`. I know there is some mistake in my code. Can anyone suggest the right thing?

Comment: you are applying SVD to each element of image. Apply on complete image in order to get SVD.
Also, you are overwriting values of U, S and V in loop.

Comment: @ Antii...basically i want to apply SVD to each block of image and my block size is 8x8 and there are 347275 blocks. This image is represented by A. Can you suggest something.